# Design decision of boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) vs boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c); in collection framework

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Why   boolean containsAll(Collection < ?>  c); method of collection framework is allowed for every type **?**.But   **boolean addAll(Collection< ?extends E>  c);**
allow for **? extends E**.So,i wrote a program for clarification.
Here is my program

```
public class ContainAllTest {
    // take ServiceDto 
    ArrayList<ServiceDto> resultList = new ArrayList<ServiceDto>();

    void Test() {

        ServiceDto serviceDto = new ServiceDto();
        serviceDto.setName("test");
        resultList.add(serviceDto);
        // another arraylist that takes String 
        ArrayList<String> resultList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        resultList1.add("test");
        // no error, goes for run time.Contain all checking is done for two generic type ServiceDto and String:
        resultList.containsAll(resultList1);
        // error shown at compile time,as addAll take ServiceDto as generic type but the generic type for resultList1 take String:
        resultList.addAll(resultList1);    
    }
```

So,my question is when can i get advantage of  resultList.containsAll(resultList1); when the generic type is different.In my case String and ServiceDto.Was there some thing wrong replacing  **boolean containsAll(Collection< ? > c)** with **boolean containsAll(Collection<  ?extends E> c)**

Comment: Equals and hashCode are methods in Object, that is <?>. When you search for a collection containing something you don't want to need to cast it to the appropriate type each time.

Comment: @artbristol: Yes, this is essentially the same question, and that has a better answer. I will vote to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: It would be tedious if I had to copy the contents of my Collection<?> to a Collection<? extends E> just so I could call containsAll(). It's essentially equivalent to the equals() method accepting a parameter of type Object. (Ok, with type erasure both Collections are just Collection<Object> and I could cast it, but that is just a hack and we should write our code as if it wouldn't work.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the reason is that `containsAll` (and `contains`, `remove`, `removeAll`) uses `Object#equals` for the comparison.

You could, conceivably, have an overriden `Object#equals` method in `E` that can return `true` for objects of some unrelated class. Not that it would be a good idea, but it could be a valid implementation.

Comment: It's sometimes a good idea. For example, `java.util.List` requires that `.equals()` return true for lists with the same content, even for different list classes.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't to give an advantage it's to save cpu ticks. Generics are [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) by the compiler and replaced with casts.

For the `addAll` method type safety needs to be taken into account. The user should only be allowed to add a `Collection<E>` or some subclass of `E` to a `Collection<E>`.

If you look at the source code for `AbstractCollection` you see this method:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

When compiled it will look (something) like

```
public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (Object e : c)
        if (add((E)e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

I.e. each and every element of the collection to be added needs to be cast from `Object` to `E` before being added.

For the `containsAll` method it doesn't matter. As the `equals` method is defined as `equals(Object other)` you can safely call it with any other `Collection` and there is no risk of `ClassCastException`s. By avoiding the use of generics the compiler can avoid adding in casts.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with "cpu ticks".

Comment: @assylias Casting ain't free. But it does also have the advantage of providing a better interface specification.

Comment: Casting is maybe not free but I don't think it has anything to do with the design of the class.

Comment: It's a single instruction (`checkcast`). I don't think it matters.

Comment: More importantly: a cast to ˋEˋ is an unchecked cast that only checks against ˋObjectˋ at runtime. So it's a no-op and **it is free** in this case! So that's certainly not the reason behind the design decision. I suspect the reason has to do with backwards compatibility.

Comment: -1 This is just wrong. There is no cast when adding the element to the collection, in none of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the same as for the methods `add` and `contains`.

`add` takes an argument of the generic type of the collection, because only such objects may be added to the collection. That's the whole point of using generics in collections.

`contains` (as well as other methods in the collection framework like `remove` and `Map.get`) accepts any object as parameter. There are at least two reasons.

First, as Tobias Brandt said, there might be objects of a completely separate type that are "equal" (as defined by their `equals` implementation) to an object in the collection.

Second, every collection `Collection<E>` can be seen as `Collection<? extends D>` where D is a super class of E, or even as `Collection<?>` (which is the same as `Collection<? extends Object>`). If you do this upcast, you can't call the `add` method anymore, because it's signature would look like `add(?)` and the compiler forbids calling it because it could never ensure type safety (and it's good that you can't call `add` because you could add wrong types to the collection). However, it might still be useful to call `contains` and this is always type safe, so why shouldn't it be allowed? In order to allow this, the `contains` method needs to have `Object` as parameter type, otherwise it could not be called similar to `add`.

The signatures of `addAll` and `containsAll` just follow this same principle.

Comment: "However, it might still be useful to call contains and this is always type safe" But this is again because `Object.equals()` takes all types. If `Object.equals()` didn't take all types, then it would not always be type safe.